# T-SQL append number to variable

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I couldn't find an answer to this....

I have three variables and need to switch between them in While Loop

Example:

```
DECLARE  
@tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX),  
@email nvarchar(100),  
@text1 nvarchar(100),
@text2 nvarchar(100),
@text3 nvarchar(100),
@number_suffix nvarchar(1)
SET @text1 = 'State of orders for Morfeus'
SET @text2 = 'State of orders for Fenix'
SET @text3 = 'State of orders for Perseus'
SET @number_suffix = 1
WHILE (@number_suffix < 4)
BEGIN
    print @text(@number_suffix) /*and here is the problem */
    SET @number_suffix = (@number_suffix + 1)
END
```

How do I append the number to variable @text please?
I am using MS SQL 2008

Comment: Do you want to append number to variable name??? Why you need that, perhaps solution is more straightforward....

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to append number to variable name? This is not possible. Why you need that, perhaps solution is more straightforward....

Try out following, perhaps id does what are you looking for:

```
DECLARE @cities TABLE(id int IDENTITY(1,1), cityName varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @cities(cityName) VALUES ('Morfeus'), ('Fenix'), ('Morfeus')    
SELECT 'State of orders for ' + cityName
FROM @cities
```

Output:

```
State of orders for Morfeus
State of orders for Fenix
State of orders for Morfeus
```

**To print number as well:**

```
SELECT '#' + CAST(id AS varchar(2)) + ' State of orders for ' + cityName
FROM @cities
```

Output:

```
1 State of orders for Morfeus 
2 State of orders for Fenix 
3 State of orders for Morfeus
```

Comment: Basically idea os SQL is relational data structures so you should operate with tables, record sets, not a tricky dynamic stuff

Answer (score 0):

The question is not quite clear what your end game is but if I understand you correctly then something like this should work (note, you need to create the parse function first):

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnParseString]
(
    @Section SMALLINT,
    @Delimiter CHAR,
    @Text VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @startindex NUMERIC(18,0),
     @length NUMERIC(18,0),
     @FieldPosition INT

 SET @FieldPosition = ABS(@Section) - 1
 SET @startindex = 0


 WHILE @FieldPosition != 0
 BEGIN
    SET @FieldPosition = @FieldPosition - 1
     SET @startindex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Text, @startindex + 1) 
 END     


 SET @Text = SUBSTRING(@Text, @startindex + 1, LEN(@Text) - @startindex)
 SET @Text = SUBSTRING(@Text, 0, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @Text))

 RETURN @Text
END
GO

DECLARE  
@tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX),  
@email nvarchar(100),  
@text nvarchar(100),
@number_suffix nvarchar(1)

SET @text = 'State of orders for Morfeus|State of orders for Fenix|State of orders for Perseus|'

SET @number_suffix = 1
WHILE (@number_suffix < 4)
BEGIN
    PRINT dbo.fnParseString(@number_suffix, '|', @text)

    SET @number_suffix = (@number_suffix + 1)
END
```

Comment: This may also work for my example Chris, but like you wrote I wasn't perfectly clear what my end game is and thus this is not going to work for my real script...  
Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Dynamic SQL but you'd need to reinitialize all you variables. The following will do it, but *its a colossally bad idea, and you should use sll's answer instead*

```
DECLARE  
@tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX),  
@email nvarchar(100),  

@number_suffix nvarchar(1),
@SQL nvarchar(max)

SET @number_suffix = 1
WHILE (@number_suffix < 4)
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = N'
    DECLARE @text1 nvarchar(100),
            @text2 nvarchar(100),
            @text3 nvarchar(100)

    SET @text1 = ' + '''' + 'State of orders for Morfeus' + ''''  +
   'SET @text2 = ' + '''' + 'State of orders for Fenix' + ''''  + 
   'SET @text3 = ' + '''' + 'State of orders for Perseus' + ''''

    +           

    'PRINT @text' + @number_suffix
    EXEC sp_executeSQL  @SQL 
    SET @number_suffix = (@number_suffix + 1)
END
```